# Firestore, applying dynamic where-based filtering

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter a collection of products/dishes based on different criteria like cuisine, taste, diet, etc.

I pass these filters as a json object like the following:

```
 {
  "tagDiet": [
    "halal",
    "vegan"
  ],
     "tagCuisine":  [
    "Other"
  ],
  "price": [9.99]
}
```

Now I want to pass these filters into firebase functions endpoint that filters the collection, the code for this endpoint contains the snippet that I want to fix:

```
const filters: any = request.body;
let query: any = productsRef;
console.log(filters)
let data: Array < any > = [];
if (filters.hasOwnProperty('price')) {
    let price = filters.price;
    delete filters['price'];
    let maxPrice = Math.max(price);
    console.log(maxPrice, price, filters);
    query = await query.where('price', '<=', maxPrice);
}
await Object.keys(filters).map(async (key: string) => {
    console.log(key, filters[key]);    
    query = await query.where(key, 'IN', filters[key]);
})
```

Although I get a response (only price filter is applied) from the requested endpoint, I still get two errors in the console (resulting from the other two filters (tagCuisine, tagDiet).

```
 (node:7596) Unhandled PromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value for argument "opStr" is invalid. Acceptable values are: <, <=, ==, !=, >, >=, array-contains, in, not-in, array-contains-any
```

```
 (node:7596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
[0] >  (node:7596) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[0] >  (node:7596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value for argument "opStr" is invalid. Acceptable values are: <, <=, ==, !=, >, >=, array-contains, in, not-in, array-contains-any
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use uppercase in this line:

```
query = await query.where(key, 'IN', filters[key]);
```

It should be

```
query = query.where(key, 'in', filters[key]);
```

---

Note that I have removed the `await` keyword: `where()` is not an asynchronous method, therefore you don't need to use `await`. On the other hand, you do need to use `await` with the asynchronous `get()` method.

The same with `await Object.keys(filters).map(async (key: string) => {..});`: no need to use `async/await` here.

Comment: Expanding on Renaud's comment a bit: ```.where()``` returns a new query, entirely locally - it does not actually access Firestore at all - which is why it is a SYNCHRONOUS operation, and does not need ```await```